# Indy Header Last-Modified - Invalid argument to date encode

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using TIdHTTP from Indy. I am issuing 2 different requests, one header contains the 'Last-Modified' tag, the other one does not. The header with the tag, throws an exception:

```
'Invalid Argument to date encode'
```

I already came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063172/cookie-expired-indy) question where [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) said, that TIdHttp is now able to parse ISO8601 dates, but it doesnt seem to work for me. As you can see below, i am not doing anything with the component other than changing the UserAgent. Am I missing something?

```
url :=  'https://api.priceapi.com/v2/jobs/' + JobID+ '?token=' + Token;
http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
http.Request.UserAgent := 'XXXXX'; //Some UserAgent
try
  ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  try
    http.IOHandler := ssl;
    try
      jo := TJsonObject.ParseJSONValue(http.get(url)) as TJSONObject;
      result := jo.GetValue('status').Value;
    finally
    end;
  finally
    ssl.Free;
  end;
finally
  http.Free;
end;
```

Header with Last-Modified:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename="20181025145103_google_shopping_de_5bd1d857bbd7e520c12841d7.json"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/json
Last-Modified: 2018-10-25 14:51:23 +0000
Vary: Origin
X-Accel-Buffering: no
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: b05aa8fe-7ea9-4152-8470-a75f9816549f
X-Runtime: 0.099212
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Header without Last-Modified:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate', nil
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', nil
ETag: W/"43c4a8865a5ebe565f3920779a962e93"', nil
Vary: Origin', nil
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff', nil
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN', nil
X-Request-Id: 344ac82e-0d14-4838-ae7e-627c79b78edc', nil
X-Runtime: 0.062357', nil
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block', nil
Content-Length: 157', nil
Connection: Close', nil
```

StackTrace:

```
:744717d2 KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x62
HIWBase.System.SysUtils.ConvertError($3B68860)
HIWBase.System.SysUtils.EncodeDate(???,???,???)
HIWBase.IdGlobalProtocols.RawStrInternetToDateTime('07:53:37 +0000',0)
HIWBase.IdGlobalProtocols.GMTToLocalDateTime('07:53:37 +0000')
HIWBase.IdHTTPHeaderInfo.TIdEntityHeaderInfo.ProcessHeaders
HIWBase.IdHTTPHeaderInfo.TIdResponseHeaderInfo.ProcessHeaders
HIWBase.IdHTTP.TIdHTTPProtocol.RetrieveHeaders(255)
HIWBase.IdHTTP.TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest('GET','My URL',nil,$ADF09E0,(...))
HIWBase.IdHTTP.TIdCustomHTTP.Get('My URL',$ADF09E0,(...))
HIWBase.IdHTTP.TIdCustomHTTP.Get('My URL',(...))
HIWBase.IdHTTP.TIdCustomHTTP.Get('My URL')
```

I am on Indy version 10.6.2.5311

Comment: well you gave the answer yourself, you are not using the latest Indy version. you can find the latest version here: https://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/ (r5479)

Comment: I thought the last part of the version is the SVN commit. So 10.6.2.5311 = Revision 5311, he committed it with 4892. Am I wrong?

Comment: The date listed is not in ISO8601 format. This format is as follows: `2018-10-26T08:37:01+00:00`, ie. no spaces, and a "T" separating the date from the time. Compare this with the date you receive: `2018-10-25 14:51:23 +0000`

Comment: @Hello_my_dog_can_code you are correct that the last number is the SVN revision. However, the current revision is 5479

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Last-Modified` header is defined in [RFC 2616 Section 14.29](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.29) <sup>1</sup> as:

```
Last-Modified  = "Last-Modified" ":" HTTP-date
```

<sup>1: An equivalent definition appears in [RFC 7232 Section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.2).</sup>

`HTTP-date` is defined in [RFC 2616 Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3) <sup>2</sup> as:

```
HTTP-date    = rfc1123-date | rfc850-date | asctime-date
rfc1123-date = wkday "," SP date1 SP time SP "GMT"
rfc850-date  = weekday "," SP date2 SP time SP "GMT"
asctime-date = wkday SP date3 SP time SP 4DIGIT
date1        = 2DIGIT SP month SP 4DIGIT
               ; day month year (e.g., 02 Jun 1982)
date2        = 2DIGIT "-" month "-" 2DIGIT
               ; day-month-year (e.g., 02-Jun-82)
date3        = month SP ( 2DIGIT | ( SP 1DIGIT ))
               ; month day (e.g., Jun  2)
time         = 2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT
               ; 00:00:00 - 23:59:59
wkday        = "Mon" | "Tue" | "Wed"
             | "Thu" | "Fri" | "Sat" | "Sun"
weekday      = "Monday" | "Tuesday" | "Wednesday"
             | "Thursday" | "Friday" | "Saturday" | "Sunday"
month        = "Jan" | "Feb" | "Mar" | "Apr"
             | "May" | "Jun" | "Jul" | "Aug"
             | "Sep" | "Oct" | "Nov" | "Dec"
```

<sup>2: Equivalent definitions appear in [RFC 7231 Section 7.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1).</sup>

The `Last-Modified` value you have shown does not match any of those formats allowed by HTTP.

`TIdHTTP` uses Indy's `GMTToLocalDateTime()` function to parse the `Last-Modified` (and `Date` and `Expires`) header.  That function is shared by HTTP, IMAP, NNTP, and email components, so it is a *little* more flexible in the date/time formats that it supports.  For instance, it does parse ISO 8601, which you claim the `Last-Modified` value is.  However, the value you have shown does not actually conform to ISO 8601, either.  If it had, it would have looked more like this instead:

```
Last-Modified: 2018-10-26T08:37:01+00:00
```

To make matters worse, according to the stack trace you have provided, `GMTToLocalDateTime()` is being called without any date portion at all:

```
HIWBase.IdGlobalProtocols.GMTToLocalDateTime('07:53:37 +0000')
```

The *only* way that can happen in `TIdHTTP` is if the HTTP server is sending a `Last-Modified` (or `Date` or `Expires`) header with that exact value, which is also not conformant to the HTTP or ISO 8601 standards, and is not handled as-is by `GMTToLocalDateTime()`.

In short, the API you are querying is sending an *illegal date/time format* that `TIdHTTP` does not support parsing (which is ironic, because the main `https://www.priceapi.com` website does send properly formatted HTTP date/time strings).  You should contact the website admin and report that their API server is violating HTTP protocol standards in this regard.

That being said, `GMTToLocalDateTime()` DOES NOT raise an `'Invalid Argument to date encode'` exception when it encounters a malformed date/time string.  It returns a `TDateTime` of `0.0` instead.  The *only* way you could be seeing that exception is if you are running your code inside the debugger.  When `GMTToLocalDateTime()` is given a malformed date/time string, it is possible that it may extract numeric components that it thinks are valid but then fails when it attempts to encode the final `TDateTime` with them.  The exception you are seeing comes from the RTL's `EncodeDate()` function when it is given an invalid month/day/year as input.  But `GMTToLocalDateTime()` catches that exception internally.  Your code will never see it at runtime, only the debugger can see it.